# Deploy a Database from a batch

Tags: sql-server, cmd

I'm trying to deploy a database (.bak / sql server 2012) by a batch(.bat) file , could you give me an example or how could I do that?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`SqlCmd` command-line tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) in a batch-file to do that. This command-line tool is installed when you install `SQL Server Management Tools – Basic`.

There is plenty of online information, this is a pseudo-code example I found:

```
SqlCmd -E -S <Server_Name> –Q “RESTORE DATABASE [Name_of_Database] FROM DISK='X:PathToBackupFile[File_Name].bak'”
```